# DocuSign : Template Radio Button Selection Programmatically through c#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I already have the radio button in DocuSign template, I want to select one of correct option from True and False programmatically. With the help of  radioGroup.Radios.Add(, I am getting overwrite button on template button. Can you please suggest the solution how i can select radio button through c# code.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup { GroupName = 
   templateField.DocuSignFieldName, DocumentId = "1", 
   Radios = new List<Radio>() }; 

radioGroup.Radios.Add(
   new Radio { PageNumber = "3", Value = "Radio 1", 
      XPosition = "52", YPosition = "344", Selected = "true", 
      TabId = templateField.DocuSignFieldName }); 

radioGroup.Radios.Add(
   new Radio { PageNumber = "3", Value = "Radio 2", 
      XPosition = "85", YPosition = "344", Selected = "false", 
      TabId = templateField.DocuSignFieldName }); 

radioTabs.Add(radioGroup);
```

Comment: RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup
{
   GroupName = templateField.DocuSignFieldName,
   DocumentId = "1",
   Radios = new List<Radio>()
};
radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { PageNumber = "3", Value = "Radio 1", XPosition = "52", YPosition = "344", Selected = "true", TabId = templateField.DocuSignFieldName });
radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { PageNumber = "3", Value = "Radio 2", XPosition = "85", YPosition = "344", Selected = "false", TabId = templateField.DocuSignFieldName });
radioTabs.Add(radioGroup);

Comment: So your template has a radio group and radio buttons in it, and you want to know how to programmatically set a value when the envelope is sent?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please cgeck (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

1. Your template has a radio group
2. When you use the API to send the envelope, you want to choose the initial value of the radio group. (If you want the radio buttons to be read-only, then use the `locked` attribute.)

You will need the `tabId` and `value` for the radio button you want to set.

Here is the request object that uses a template on the server, and then sets the name/email of the signer, and sets which radio button is selected.

```
{
    "envelopeDefinition": {
        "status": "sent",
        "compositeTemplates": [
            {
                "compositeTemplateId": "1",
                "serverTemplates": [
                    {
                        "sequence": "1",
                        "templateId": "12345-678-91023"
                    }
                ],
                "inlineTemplates": [
                    {
                        "sequence": "1",
                        "recipients": {
                            "signers": [
                                {
                                    "email": "larry@example.com",
                                    "name": "Larry K",
                                    "roleName": "Signer1",
                                    "recipientId": "1",
                                    "tabs": {
                                        "radioGroupTabs": [
                                            {
                                                "groupName": "Radio Group 1",
                                                "radios": [
                                                    {
                                                        "selected": "true",
                                                        "tabId": "615d0f54-8754-459e-9f79-e72ad427557c",
                                                        "value": "Radio3"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the same JSON when it is created with the C# SDK

```
            ServerTemplate serverTemplate1 = new ServerTemplate
            {
                Sequence = "1",  
                TemplateId = "12345-678-91023" 
            };
            List<ServerTemplate> serverTemplates1 = new List<ServerTemplate> {serverTemplate1};
            Radio radio1 = new Radio
            {
                Selected = "true",  
                TabId = "615d0f54-8754-459e-9f79-e72ad427557c",  
                Value = "Radio3" 
            };
            List<Radio> radios1 = new List<Radio> {radio1};
            RadioGroup radioGroupTab1 = new RadioGroup
            {
                GroupName = "Radio Group 1",  
                Radios = radios1 
            };
            List<RadioGroup> radioGroupTabs1 = new List<RadioGroup> {radioGroupTab1};
            Tabs tabs1 = new Tabs
            {
                RadioGroupTabs = radioGroupTabs1 
            };
            Signer signer1 = new Signer
            {
                Email = "larry@example.com",  
                Name = "Larry K",  
                RecipientId = "1",  
                RoleName = "Signer1",  
                Tabs = tabs1 
            };
            List<Signer> signers1 = new List<Signer> {signer1};
            Recipients recipients1 = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = signers1 
            };
            InlineTemplate inlineTemplate1 = new InlineTemplate
            {
                Recipients = recipients1,  
                Sequence = "1" 
            };
            List<InlineTemplate> inlineTemplates1 = new List<InlineTemplate> {inlineTemplate1};
            CompositeTemplate compositeTemplate1 = new CompositeTemplate
            {
                CompositeTemplateId = "1",  
                InlineTemplates = inlineTemplates1,  
                ServerTemplates = serverTemplates1 
            };
            List<CompositeTemplate> compositeTemplates1 = new List<CompositeTemplate> {compositeTemplate1};
            EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                CompositeTemplates = compositeTemplates1,  
                Status = "sent" 
            };

            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            try
            {
                EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
                Console.WriteLine($"Envelope status: {results.Status}. Envelope ID: {results.EnvelopeId}");
                return results.EnvelopeId;
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception while creating envelope!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Code: {e.ErrorCode}\nContent: {e.ErrorContent}");
                //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes Larry K you are absolutely right, I have got the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the correct answer .

```
                     RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup
                    {

                        GroupName = templateField.DocuSignFieldName,
                        Radios = new List<Radio>()

                    };
                    if (_applicationAnswerMapService.GetRadioboxFieldValue(templateField, application) == "true")
                    {
                        radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { Value = "Radio1", Selected = "true" });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { Value = "Radio2", Selected = "false" });
                    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).